# What type of military uniform is this?

Tags: military, france, identification, uniform

I'm researching a CDV I bought this past summer and am having great difficulty finding what type of uniform this is. I have it narrowed down to a French military uniform, likely post 1900. I was able to find two other examples of the same uniform on different men (with different identifiers on the collar of each), but they exist on a stock photo website, so they contain no additional information.
[image]
[Stock Photo 1](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-old-and-damaged-photo-of-a-french-soldier-1900s-39947220.html?pv=1&stamp=2&imageid=CCD413E5-02D5-474E-ABEC-1A63C1E7DC98&p=160400&n=0&orientation=0&pn=1&searchtype=0&IsFromSearch=1&srch=foo%3Dbar%26st%3D0%26pn%3D1%26ps%3D100%26sortby%3D2%26resultview%3DsortbyPopular%26npgs%3D0%26qt%3Duniform%2520of%2520the%2520french%2520army%25201900%26qt_raw%3Duniform%2520of%2520the%2520french%2520army%25201900%26lic%3D3%26mr%3D0%26pr%3D0%26ot%3D0%26creative%3D%26ag%3D0%26hc%3D0%26pc%3D%26blackwhite%3D%26cutout%3D%26tbar%3D1%26et%3D0x000000000000000000000%26vp%3D0%26loc%3D0%26imgt%3D0%26dtfr%3D%26dtto%3D%26size%3D0xFF%26archive%3D1%26groupid%3D%26pseudoid%3D%26a%3D%26cdid%3D%26cdsrt%3D%26name%3D%26qn%3D%26apalib%3D0%26apalic%3D%26lightbox%3D%26gname%3D%26gtype%3D%26xstx%3D0%26simid%3D%26saveQry%3D%26editorial%3D1%26nu%3D%26t%3D%26edoptin%3D%26customgeoip%3D%26cap%3D1%26cbstore%3D1%26vd%3D0%26lb%3D%26fi%3D2%26edrf%3D0)
[Stock Photo 2](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-young-adult-male-person-posing-in-military-uniform-france-1910s-87791501.html?pv=1&stamp=2&imageid=787C9A21-BFB1-4C26-A143-2746E8B0A092&p=160400&n=0&orientation=0&pn=1&searchtype=0&IsFromSearch=1&srch=foo%3Dbar%26st%3D0%26pn%3D1%26ps%3D100%26sortby%3D2%26resultview%3DsortbyPopular%26npgs%3D0%26qt%3D1910s%2520style%26qt_raw%3D1910s%2520style%26lic%3D3%26mr%3D0%26pr%3D0%26ot%3D0%26creative%3D%26ag%3D0%26hc%3D0%26pc%3D%26blackwhite%3D%26cutout%3D%26tbar%3D1%26et%3D0x000000000000000000000%26vp%3D0%26loc%3D0%26imgt%3D0%26dtfr%3D%26dtto%3D%26size%3D0xFF%26archive%3D1%26groupid%3D%26pseudoid%3D%26a%3D%26cdid%3D%26cdsrt%3D%26name%3D%26qn%3D%26apalib%3D0%26apalic%3D%26lightbox%3D%26gname%3D%26gtype%3D%26xstx%3D0%26simid%3D%26saveQry%3D%26editorial%3D1%26nu%3D%26t%3D%26edoptin%3D%26customgeoip%3D%26cap%3D1%26cbstore%3D1%26vd%3D0%26lb%3D%26fi%3D2%26edrf%3D)

Can anyone tell me what type of uniform this is, the likely year(s), and any other information?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please explain what a CDV is?

Answer (score 19):

This is a French soldier from the [13th Batallion](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/13e_bataillon_de_chasseurs_alpins) [Chasseurs Alpins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasseurs_Alpins). They are light infantry mountain troops.

Comment: Here's a reenactor, cane and all. http://i69.servimg.com/u/f69/18/11/11/23/linge-10.jpg  That's from a Hommes de Guerre No 9 article by [Philippe Conrad](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Ffr.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPhilippe_Conrad&edit-text=&act=url).